# Vector by vector derivative

Tags: derivatives

I want to solve the derivative of $\mathbf{f}=\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{x}\mathbf{c}^T$ with respect to $\mathbf{x}$, where $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{x}$ are $M\times 1$ vectors, and $\mathbf{c}$ is a $N \times 1$ vector. $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{c}$ are independent of $\mathbf{x}$. I tried the following procedure:
$$ 
\partial\mathbf{f} = \mathbf{a}^T\partial\mathbf{x}\mathbf{c}^T=\mathbf{c}^T\mathbf{a}^T\partial\mathbf{x}
$$
But I cannot directly get $\frac{\partial\mathbf{f}}{\partial\mathbf{x}}$. Could someone please help me with this derivative? Thanks.

Comment: What is the context? What are the sizes of the vectors? And, are $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf c$ constant vectors or do they depend on $\mathbf x$ ? Without further context and some details on your attempts towards a solution, your question is phrased as an _isolated_ question and is unlikely to get an answer here.

Comment: In general, the equality $$\mathbf{a}^T\partial\mathbf{x}\mathbf{c}^T=\mathbf{c}^T\mathbf{a}^T\partial\mathbf{x}$$ does not hold unless the matrices commute.

Comment: @sadman-ncc, Thanks, I have edited it. Now, the equality $\mathbf{a}^T\partial\mathbf{x}\mathbf{c}^T=\mathbf{c}^T\mathbf{a}^T\partial\mathbf{x}$ holds, because $\mathbf{a}^T\partial\mathbf{x}$ is a scalar.

Comment: You can use this [online tool](http://www.matrixcalculus.org) to compute derivatives of scalars/vectors/matrices. It's really great to do actual computations.

Comment: @PC1.Thanks! But I found the results of $\frac{\partial\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{x}\mathbf{c}^T}{\partial\mathbf{x}}$ and $\frac{\partial\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{x}\mathbf{c}}{\partial\mathbf{x}}$ are the same, but I do not know the procedure.

Comment: There are various definitions of derivative with respect to vector. You'll need to choose the definition first. $\vec{f}$ is $N$-vector, $\vec{x}$ is $M$-vector. Then one of possible choices is that derivative is matrix with elements, satisfying $\left(\frac{\partial \vec{f}}{\partial \vec{x}}\right)_{ij}=\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}=c_ia_j$